# In Locust, can I modify the number of users and hatch rate after I start the test?

Tags: python, locust

After I launch Locust without the web UI:
$ locust -f locust_files/my_locust_file.py --no-web -c 1000 -r 100

is it possible to change the number of users or hatch rate programmatically during the execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.. that is not possible.. Locust requires the number of virtual users and hatch rate to be defined at test startup.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Guess I have to chain the tests somehow to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 2):

This an old question, but perhaps, somebody may face this problem.
Fortunately, Locust have grate [shape](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/custom-load-shape.html) functionality.
In your `main.py`:

```
env = Environment(
    user_classes=[DefaultHttpClass], 
    host=registry.config.host,
    shape_class=ShapeClass()
)
env.create_local_runner()

env.create_web_ui("127.0.0.1", 8089)

extended_api = ExtendedApi(env)

env.runner.start(CURRENT_USERS, spawn_rate=SPAWN_RATE)
env.runner.start_shape()
```

In your custom API class add new method to update constants

```
class ExtendedApi:

def __init__(self, env: Environment) -> None:
    self._env = env

    @self._env.web_ui.app.route(f'/update_current_test/', methods=['POST'])
    def update_current_test() -> Response:
        utils.consts.CURRENT_USERS = request.json.get('user_count')
        utils.consts.SPAWN_RATE = request.json.get('spawn_rate')
        return Response(status=200)
```

And now, subclass Shape and add rules:

```
class MyCustomShape(LoadTestShape):

def tick(self):
    if consts.CURRENT_USERS == 0:
        return None
    return (consts.CURRENT_USERS, consts.SPAWN_RATE)
```

Now after calling method with

```
{
"user_count": 160,
"spawn_rate": 10.0
}
```

your shape changes test

Answer (score 1):

### Warning: unsupported method

Start locust in the usual way and investigate the calls made by the browser to the endpoints exposed by locust.

E.g. the call to update the user count is a simple POST to the /swarm endpoint with the desired locust count and hatch rate:

`curl "http://localhost:8089/swarm" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data "locust_count=10&hatch_rate=1"`

Comment: It's related to a web-ui mode only, don't think it's a common way to run Locust tests

Answer (score 0):

1) If we want to increase the number of users during test:

Run the same test in parallel with additional number of users

2) If we want to decrease the number of users during test:

a) Run the second test with required number of users

b) At the same time stop the first test

Both options can be automated with python or even bash scripts.

Dirty hack, but I think this will result desirable effect completely.