# Locust : How to simulate a custom number of users for my test?

Tags: python, locust

Edit : Resolved (go to the end of the post at Edit 2 :)

I would like, instead of the user spawn that I can get from the Locust interface, to be able to choose how much users will spawn and when they will.

To do that, I have my scenario that launch the requests, that I called User_data.
And I have created another class "User_launch" that I want to use to simulate the number of users and launch the User_data scenario with the number of users that I chose.

```
import asyncio
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task, between

class UserLaunch(HttpUser):
    is_running = True  

    def on_start(self):
        self.user_data = self.get_taskset_instance(UserData)

    @task
    def launch_scenario(self):
        for target_users in [1, 10, 30, 60, 100]:
            while self.user_data.num_users < target_users:
                self.user_data.num_users += 1
                self.user_data.run()
                self.wait(2)  

            self.wait(180)

        if self.is_running:
            self.environment.runner.quit()
            self.is_running = False
```

What I wanted to try here was to create some users levels. First the number of users goes from 1 to 10 (1 user created every 2 second). When it reach 10, it waits for 3 minutes, and then goes to the next level.
During all this time, I want the current users to continue running tests.
But my problem is that the command self.user_data.run() will only run one time when it's launched, and wait until the end to go to the next action.

So, is it possible to tell every user that is created to continue launching tests until the end of the simulation, even when new users are been generated and during the 3 minutes during which no user is generated ?

Edit : I just saw a post here [In Locust, can I modify the number of users and hatch rate after I start the test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54202932/in-locust-can-i-modify-the-number-of-users-and-hatch-rate-after-i-start-the-tes)
saying that we can use the LoadtestShape option to modify the number of users and spawn rate when we want. Im gonna try that and come back to you once it works.

Edit 2 : The LoadTestShape option works perfectly.
You can go there to know more about it
https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/custom-load-shape.html
In my case, I did that.

```
class User_launch(LoadTestShape):
    stages = [
        {"duration": 60, "users": 1, "spawn_rate": 1, "user_classes": [User_view]},
        {"duration": 198, "users": 10, "spawn_rate": 0.5, "user_classes": [User_view]},
        {"duration": 358, "users": 30, "spawn_rate": 0.5, "user_classes": [User_view]},
        {"duration": 538, "users": 60, "spawn_rate": 0.5, "user_classes": [User_view]},
        {"duration": 700, "users": 100, "spawn_rate": 0.5, "user_classes": [User_view]}
    ]
    def tick(self):
        run_time = self.get_run_time()
        for stage in self.stages:
            if run_time < stage["duration"]:
                try:
                    tick_data = (stage["users"], stage["spawn_rate"], stage["user_classes"])
                except:
                    tick_data = (stage["users"], stage["spawn_rate"])
                return tick_data

        return None
```

With that, my user_spawn is 1 user every 2 second. And after, I stay 2 minutes with the same number of users before adding more.
At the "stages" variable, the "duration" and "users" variables are the total  time and user numbers of the test. Meaning, that you can reduce the number of users during the test.

Anyway, I put that here, it will maybe help somebody.
But I don't know how to close the question, so if somebody can or know how to close it, I would be happy to know.

Comment: If you can be bothered, feel free to rewrite your solution as an answer and accept it, that will help future readers here :)